# CUDA Ignore Error, Check failed: e == cudaSuccess: CUDA: initialization error

Tags: mxnet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARTI2.png)

This problem always seems to occur between two cross validation, reloading the model to the GPU

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks some needed info:

1. Your OS (Windows or Linux (Ubuntu, Debian or what you need)
2. Your GPU/CPU info
3. Your CUDA version
4. Your installed mxnet version (which I guess you installed with `pip install` .

If you provide this details, we may dig further to find the root cause of the error.